# Detect underscore and caret characters in iOS/objective-C

Tags: ios, string, special-characters, unichar

I need to detect whether a unichar is equal to an underscore (_) or a caret (^). I'm currently doing it like this:

```
unichar ch;
NSString *chAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", ch];
if ([chAsString isEqualToString:@"_"])
    // ... do something ...
else if ([chAsString isEqualToString:@"^"])
    // ... do something else...
```

Question #1: Is this method safe, i.e., will I catch all possible encodings of these characters?

Question #2: Is this the cleanest way to do this? It seems awfully clunky. But I get the sense it is more reliable than `if (ch == 0x5F)`, etc.

Comment: The best way to do it, for characters with values below 0x7f, is to compare the character values -- `if (ch == '_')...`.  It gets a little trickier with extended Unicode characters.

Comment: And there is only one "possible encoding" of a given Unicode character.

Comment: Thanks. This works. For some reason I thought `if (ch == '_')` didn't. You can make this an answer and I'll vote it.

Comment: It's a little tricky for characters that are above 0x7f.  For those you should use the hex Unicode numeric value, rather than the single-quoted character, since the single-quoted character is as standard C `char` (8 bit) rather than a `Unichar`.

Comment: @HotLicks, OK, thanks for the clarification. Like I said, please post as an answer and I'll vote it.

Comment: I don't do answers.  You can accept one of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to compare string. You can compare each character. Try this:

```
if (ch == '_')
    // ... do something ...
else if (ch == '^')
    // ... do something else...
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
NSString *str = @"string";
const char *myChar = "some string";
if (strcmp(myChar,  str.UTF8String))
```

or

```
[str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:myChar]];
```